# how to implement deep recursion on CUDA

Tags: cuda

What is the most efficient way to implement deep recursion on CUDA (thousands of levels),
and where to find code examples for this if the recursion is for traversal of a tree-like data structure?

I just implemented recursion on a K20 GPU using Cuda Dynamic Parallelism, but found out that there is a limit of 24 levels due to parameter
cudaLimitDevRuntimeSyncDepth

I want to achieve max. speed and scaling for large data.

Comment: Are you sure this is something you want?  "Traversing tree-like data" isn't exactly the perfect task for a GPU...

Comment: Why not? If not, then what is the best parallel method for a CPU?

Comment: I'm no GPU expert, but I'm pretty sure that lots of conditional memory accesses would severely limit your throughput.

Comment: But we could scale for large widths of the tree.

Comment: Yes, I guess if each thread is executing the same path, and if there's enough parallelism to hide the memory accesses, then you may be ok.

Comment: If you are thinking of thousands of levels, pure recursion will not make it as the stack memory requirement would probably be quite large. Do not if it can swap of stacks to global memory, but this would also give you a penalty when you surface as you have to read in the stack frames from local memory. I would suggest you to do a pseudo recursion using a loop instead.

Comment: What do you mean by pseudo recursion using a loop?

Comment: @user1760748 As the answer below said, you should try to implement the stack frames you self, knowing what to keep, what to throw away and what you can merge into one variable. CPU E.g. calculating the Fibonacci number which is a recurrence relation is naively implemented using recursion, but getting the Nth number where N is large, will more often than not result in stack-overflow. However you could easily implement it using a for loop and solving it for large numbers easily.

Answer (score 7):

In my experience, the most reliable and efficient way of managing recursion in CUDA is to manage your recursion stack manually and "flatten" the function. If, for example, you are traversing a binary tree, it would look something like this:

```
while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
  Node n = stack.pop();
  ... //do stuff with n
  if (!n.isLeaf()) {
    stack.push(n.left());
    stack.push(n.right());
  } 
}
```

The above technique can help any code (CUDA or single-threaded CPU). Stack functionality has to be implemented by you since you don't want to use STL.

---

The next step -- more specific to CUDA -- would be to evaluate if each node needs to be processed by separate thread, or perhaps a whole warp or block or even whole grid can be assigned to it. Depending on this, `stack` should be located either in local, shared or global memory space and its member function should behave uniformly across the corresponding executing unit (thread/block/grid).

Do note, that if you want per-thread `stack` in local memory you will use a lot of memory (10000 threads x 1000 max depth recursion) and you may hit much thread divergence lowering your performance.

On the other hand --- per-block `stack` will require less memory but `__syncthreads()` will be needed.

If there is enough parallel work do to per node, I would strongly suggest per-warp or per-block processing of the node.

---

Finally, if you have stack in shared memory but you find that you need work per-warp, you may consider using atomic operations for `push` and `pop` and introduce work-stealing technique to balance your work better between warps.
Work stealing can be also done if you need a block-per-node processing by having a single stack in global memory.

---

**Edit:** 
If you need to walk up the tree, after processing it down, you can push the up direction later into the tree.

```
struct StackEntry {
    Node* node;
    bool goingUp;
};

while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
  StackEntry entry = stack.pop();
  ... //do stuff with entry.node
  if (!entry.goingUp && !entry.node->isLeaf()) {
    stack.push(StackEntry(entry.node->left(),false));
    stack.push(StackEntry(entry.node->right(),false));
    stack.push(StackEntry(entry.node,true));
  } 
}
```

Assuming each node has a pointer to its parent (or you can introduce such pointer in `StackEntry` struct), you can pass the parameters up the tree.

Do note however that this introduces dependency between the entries in the stack. This is fine as long as only one executing unit (thread/block/grid) is pushing/poping from the stack. However, if one stack is shared by many executors, using work stealing algorithms discussed earlier, it may break the dependencies. Additional thought would have to be made to prevent that.

You may want to reorganize what exactly `StackEntry` is storing and when elements are pushed onto the stack. The above approach is not the only one!

Comment: In my case, I also need to go back up the tree after reaching the leaves, becuase the result for each node in the tree depends on teh results for the children nodes. How will you suggest that I implement the stack in that case? Thank you!